# Make browser use srcset images on desktop

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser-addons, high-resolution

When browsing the web on 3840px screen I often zoom in to actually be able to use web sites. It seems however that neither Chrome or Forefox will make use of the `srcset` directives on such occasions, meaning that even for sites with `srcset` on all images (e.g. Wikipedia), pic look really ugly. Is there any browser extension, or other hack, I could use to make my browser display hires images when available? I prefer to use Chrome, Firefox or Vivaldi, so it would be great with something that works for one of them!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the answer is as simple as “reload the page”. When reloading, the best suited image is loaded in **Chrome**, **Firefox** and **Vivaldi** alike. **Opera**, on the other hand, does not seem to be using hires images even after reload.